# How would taking an "X raised by Y" trait via the Adopted trait work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits

Let's say I'm a non Half-Orc and I use [Adopted](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/adopted/) take [Iron Control (Half-Orc raised by Humans)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/iron-control-racial-trait-half-orc-raised-by-humans/).

Would I have to be adopted by Half-Orcs, get disowned or otherwise lose my Half-Orc parents, then get re-adopted by Humans? Would I have to find a Half-Orc orphan, learn their ways of rage, and then get adopted by Humans with the Half-Orc so they'd raise us the same? Could I just be born abnormally angry and the Humans who adopt me decide to raise me like they would a Half-Orc? God forbid anyone tries to trace my lineage.

Comment: When linking things (abilities/spells/etc) in a question, it's helpful to quote the relevant portions of the link....that way we don't have to go look it up in order to give you an answer.

Comment: Also, there is the possibility that in the future, the linked page may be moved, making the links provided, and the question no longer useful to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adopted has you pick a race trait associated with your adoptive parents’ race. So it seems to be that you could only choose Iron Control if your *parents* are half-orcs who were raised by humans. That, or else you simply cannot choose Iron Control, since it makes you pick *a race* associated with your parents and Iron Control requires a particular combination of races.